# CSS - Can't change width/height of textbox for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, textbox, height, width

I've encountered a problem when I'm trying to adjust my CSS after the user-device dimensions. I'm using the following code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
#form input[type=text]
  {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 95px -60px 0 15px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 3px 1px grey;
  border:1px lightgrey solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: times;
  font-size: 10px;
}
}
```

All settings apply properly and change the original CSS except the dimensions, which remain the same. How is this even possible? Is this a CSS bug? If some do apply the selector is correct and all, but the dimensions don't. It's not a cache problem, and I've tried on several devices.

I very much appreciate the help,
Fredrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post a link to your code?

Does the problem only occur on a mobile device? What happens when you resize the browser window to a width less than 700px?

Typically this kind of error is due to having selectors that are too specific somewhere else in your code, which makes them hard to override.

Try adding !important to the end of your declaration to see if the style can be overridden. Beware its generally bad practice to leave !important in there, so if that works for you search your code for the offending selectors and adjust it until your media query can override.

Comment: Thanks alot for the response. 

Adding !important does indeed work, which is weird since there is no other defintion of these properties apart from the normal one. Besides, if there was an interference between properties, wouldn't all of them be completely overridden? Only the actual dimensions of the textbox wouldn't take effect, the rest worked fine.

Could you elaborate why using !important is bad practice in specific terms? Is there anything to look out for, compatibility wise perhaps?

Again, thanks alot!

Comment: It is really hard to tell without seeing your code. It is bad practice for a couple of reasons. First the important declaration isn't supported by all browsers. Internet explorer for example. But since you are using it in a mobile page it might work for you. Be sure to check a few versions of mobile browsers on both android and iPhones.

Comment: Second you are basically telling the browser do disregard any attempt to alter the selector anywhere else in the document which is contradictory to the term "Cascading Style Sheets". Lastly any time you want to override that style later in the style sheet you will have to add important again which perpetuates the problem and increases file size to your css document.